# How do I create an ECS Service using AWS CDK in a VPC with more than 16 subnets

Tags: aws-cdk

When creating a FargateService using the AWS CDK, I'm getting the following error:

> subnets can have at most 16 items.

I have this code to create the service:

```
 var ecsService = new FargateService(this, $"{serviceNameHyphen}-service", new FargateServiceProps
 {
    TaskDefinition = taskDefinition,
    AssignPublicIp = false,
    Cluster = infrastructureStack.EcsCluster,
    CloudMapOptions = new CloudMapOptions
    {
          Name = serviceName,
          DnsRecordType = DnsRecordType.A,
          DnsTtl = Duration.Seconds(60),
          FailureThreshold = 2d
    },
    DesiredCount = 1,
    HealthCheckGracePeriod = Duration.Seconds(60),
    MaxHealthyPercent = 200,
    MinHealthyPercent = 100,
    PlatformVersion = FargatePlatformVersion.LATEST,
    ServiceName = $"{serviceNameHyphen}-service",
    SecurityGroup = albSecurityGroup,
    VpcSubnets = new SubnetSelection
    {
         OnePerAz = true,
         SubnetType = SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    }
});
```

Can the subnets be filtered?

Alternatively, the `SubnetSelection` class has a `SubnetGroup` property - I know some AWS services allow the creation of a subnet group, but I can't see how to create an arbitrary subnet group to use for the Fargate services.

**Update**
I now only have 15 subnets in the VPC but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Are you importing an existing VPC?

Comment: Yes, importing an existing VPC. For now I'm working to reduce the number of subnets in the VPC to go below the limit of 16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are importing an existing VPC you can solve this by importing a subset of your subnets by using `ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes()` instead of using `ec2.Vpc.fromLookup()`:

```ts
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, 'Vpc', {
  vpcId: 'vpc-xxxxxxxx',
  availabilityZones: ['eu-west-1a', 'eu-west-1b', 'eu-west-1c'],
  publicSubnetIds: ['subnet-xxxxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxxxx'],
  privateSubnetIds: ['subnet-xxxxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxxxx', 'subnet-xxxxxxxx']
});
```

With this, from you CDK application's point of view, your VPC will only have 3 public subnets.